# Django's formset to edit partly predefined data

Tags: django, django-forms

Here's my domain model:

```
class Seat(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=8)

class Event(models.Model):
    ...

class Occupation(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, related_name='occupations')
    seat = models.ForeignKey(Seat)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

(`Seat` is a small table, like 5-10 records.)

We have an UI requirements for a **event** edit page to look like this:

```
[1-01] [enter number]
[1-02] [enter number]
[1-03] [enter number]
[2-01] [enter number]
[2-02] [enter number]
[2-03] [enter number]
```

User navigates to **event's occupation** page where they see a list of all **seats** from system and prompted to fill **numbers** from the external source into the system.

Since the **seats** table is pretty small and to prevent errors like choosing same **seat** twice, we're required to display all seats pre-fill into the form and locked, so the user can't change **seat** selection and only limited to enter corresponding **numbers**.

Also, *seats* can be added or removed, so we can't make a "static" form with 6 predefined rows.

I suppose it should be a Django's inline model formset with a form like

```
class OccupationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Occupation
        fields = ('seat', 'number')

    ...
```

But I'm not sure how should I display a prefilled form, prevent an user from changing **seats** (and not just a client-side locking via `disabled` or javascript)

Comment: You have a specific interface / UI need. I wouldn't use the admin for this. The admin is a free CRUD interface for admins mostly. Use plain python, JS, HTML, CSS to build exactly the form you need with exactly the behavior. You can easily extend the admin with `ModelAdmin.get_urls` , and extending django `base.html`.

Comment: It's not a part of admin interface. Yes, we're free to use a full Django power, but we're also try to behave in a DRY way, writing less code, using Django's built-in forms & formsets' features if possible

Answer (score 2):

First set `seat` widget to `HiddenInput` and add the `seat_name` property to the form. This property will be used later in the HTML template:

```
class OccupationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Occupation
        fields = ('seat', 'number')
        widgets = {'seat': forms.HiddenInput}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OccupationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['number'].required = False
        self.seat_name = self.initial['seat'].name
```

Then populate `initial` data with the seats and numbers for the event.  Pass this `initial` to the formset.  Validate and save formset as usual:

```
from django.forms.formsets import formset_factory

def update_seats(request, event_id):

    event = Event.objects.get(pk=event_id)
    numbers = dict((o.seat, o.number) for o in event.occupations.all())
    initial = [{'seat': seat, 'number': numbers.get(seat, '')}
                                            for seat in Seat.objects.all()]

    OccupationFormSet = formset_factory(OccupationForm,
                                     min_num=len(initial), validate_min=True,
                                     max_num=len(initial), validate_max=True,
                                     extra=0)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = OccupationFormSet(request.POST, initial=initial)
        if formset.is_valid():
            for form in formset:
                seat = form.initial['seat']
                number = form.cleaned_data.get('number', '').strip()
                if number:
                    Occupation.objects.update_or_create(
                                                 event=event, seat=seat,
                                                 defaults={'number': number})
                else:
                    Occupation.objects.filter(event=event, seat=seat).delete()
            return redirect('.')
    else:
        formset = OccupationFormSet(initial=initial)

    return render(request, 'update_seats.html', {'formset': formset})
```

And `update_seats.html` template in which we show seat name as `{{ form.seat_name }}`:

```
<form action="" method="post">

    {% csrf_token %}

    <table>
        {{ formset.management_form }}

        <tr>
            <th>Seat</th>
            <th>Number</th>
        </tr>

        {% for form in formset %}
        <tr>
            <td>[{{ form.seat_name }}]{{ form.seat }}</td>
            <td>{{ form.number }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}

    </table>

    <button>Update</button>

</form>
```

Comment: It doesn't work well with editing/updating or situations when you fill only some numbers first, then return to fill the rest of the table. Initial data gets mixed with instance data

Comment: It does work just fine with previous occupation data.  Pass the occupied numbers in the `initial` and formset will show them.  The only thing to note is that simple formset is more suitable for this task than modelformset.  I added the full example.